# Accessing CSS media query rules via JavaScript/DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom, media-queries

I've been using a number of libraries (including my own) to dynamically load assets based upon media queries I've outlined in CSS files. For example:

In CSS:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .foo {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

**And** using an asset loader; [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), [modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/) etc or using `window.matchMedia` and associated `addListener()` functions:

```
  if (function("screen and (max-width: 480px)")){
    // Load several files
    load(['mobile.js','mobile.css']);
  }
```

Declaring them twice is awkward/silly and as far as I can find, all JS helper libraries and asset loaders require you to repeat the media queries rather than locating them **programmatically** from JS/DOM.

So, I've been exploring the ability to access the values programmatically via `document.stylesheets`, but I'm not sure if they're accessible and there seems very little documentation to suggest they are.

The furthest I've got is looking for `CSSMediaRule` and using `console.dir(document.stylesheets)` amongst others to explore the stylesheet object.

But no references are made (within `document.stylesheets`) to the actual media query rules used in CSS - only the classes to be applied as a result of the media queries... What I'm trying to locate, programmatically, is:

> "screen and (max-width: 480px)"

Is there any way of accessing such CSS Media query **rules** via JavaScript/DOM?

Comment: Oops, wrong link, [here's the article I was looking for at coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/_ldtkg)

Comment: Good question.  For my purposes, I've always checked if specific elements were visible or not, as my JavaScript interaction would apply to those elements.  There should be a better, more general solution however.

Comment: Hey, check it. It can be a solution. https://github.com/nathansmith/adapt/blob/master/assets/js/adapt.js

Comment: @steveax That's not what I was looking directly for, but, it's a fantastic alternative/leftfield approach - which solves my problem Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For get rules use cross browser variant:

```
var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = styleSheet.cssRules || styleSheet.rules; // IE <= 8 use "rules" property
```

For detect CSSMediaRule object in rules list use (not work in IE <= 8, because "CSSMediaRule" class available only in IE >= 9):

```
var i = 0;
if (rules[i].type == 4)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Some functions for get styles from current DOM (not works in IE <= 8):

```
function getCssRulesFromDocumentStyleSheets(media)
{
    var resultCssRules = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
    {
        var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];

        if (isRuleFromMedia(styleSheet, media))
            resultCssRules += getCssRulesFromRuleList(styleSheet.cssRules || styleSheet.rules, media);
    }

    return resultCssRules;
}

function getCssRulesFromRuleList(rules, media)
{
    var resultCssRules = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
    {
        var rule = rules[i];
        if (rule.type == 1) // CSSStyleRule
        {
            resultCssRules += rule.cssText + "\r\n";
        }
        else if (rule.type == 3) // CSSImportRule
        {
            if (isRuleFromMedia(rule, media))
                resultCssRules += getCssRulesFromRuleList(rule.styleSheet.cssRules || rule.styleSheet.rules, media);
        }
        else if (rule.type == 4) // CSSMediaRule
        {
            if (isRuleFromMedia(rule, media))
                resultCssRules += getCssRulesFromRuleList(rule.cssRules || rule.rules, media);
        }
    }

    return resultCssRules;
}

function isRuleFromMedia(ruleOrStyleSheet, media)
{
    while (ruleOrStyleSheet)
    {
        var mediaList = ruleOrStyleSheet.media;
        if (mediaList)
        {
            if (!isMediaListContainsValue(mediaList, media) && !isMediaListContainsValue(mediaList, 'all') && mediaList.length > 0)
                return false;
        }

        ruleOrStyleSheet = ruleOrStyleSheet.ownerRule || ruleOrStyleSheet.parentRule || ruleOrStyleSheet.parentStyleSheet;
    }

    return true;
}

function isMediaListContainsValue(mediaList, media)
{
    media = String(media).toLowerCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < mediaList.length; i++)
    {
        // Access to mediaList by "[index]" notation now work in IE (tested in versions 7, 8, 9)
        if (String(mediaList.item(i)).toLowerCase() == media)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Functions usage example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        p { margin: 10px; }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        p { margin: 15px; }
    }

    @media print {
        p { margin: 20px; }
    }
</style>

<!-- ... -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(getCssRulesFromDocumentStyleSheets('print'));
    alert(getCssRulesFromDocumentStyleSheets('screen and (max-width: 480px)'));
    // For IE (no space after colon), you can add fix to "isMediaListContainsValue" function
    alert(getCssRulesFromDocumentStyleSheets('screen and (max-width:480px)'));
</script>
```

Here is a JS Fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/hyentcqc/

Comment: this function looks for the exact match, e.g. "screen and (max…" and not for a partial match e.g. "screen", right?
I'm trying to clone, delete and re-create classes for screen (no matter what dimensions) to "all" (since I can't just change the media for existing rules)
Do you think this could be used for that?
thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it:

In css create classes to expose or hide content at various breakpoints.
This is a handy utility anyway. These are already available in Twitter Bootstrap for example.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .visible-sm, .visible-md, .visible-lg{
    display:none;
  }
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .visible-sm{
       display: block;
     }
  }
  @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 960px) {
     .visible-md{
       display: block;
     }
  }
  @media (min-width: 961px) {
     .visible-lg{
       display: block;
     }
  }
</style>
```

In all your documents add empty spans with these classes.
They won't show up on the page if you keep the spans inline.

```
<span id="media_test">
  <span class="visible-sm"></span>
  <span class="visible-md"></span>
  <span class="visible-lg"></span>
</span>
```

Add this short jquery extension to your script file.
This sets a new class in the body tag that matches the current media query.

```
(function ($) { 
  $.fn.media_size = function () {
    //the default port size
    var size = 'lg';
    //the sizes used in the css
    var sizes = ['sm','md','lg'];
    //loop over to find which is not hidden
    for (var i = sizes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     if($('#media_test .visible-'+sizes[i]).css("display").indexOf('none') == -1){
      size = sizes[i];
      break;
     };
    };
    //add a new class to the body tag
    $('body').removeClass(sizes.join(' ')).addClass(size);
  }
}(jQuery));
$(document).media_size();
```

Now you have an automatic integration with your css media queries Modernizr style.

You can write javascript (jquery) that is conditional on based on your media queries:

```
<a href="#">how big is this viewport?</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.sm a').click(function(e){ alert('Media queries say I\'m a small viewport');});
  $('.lg a').click(function(e){ alert('Media queries say I\'m a large viewport');});
</script>
```