# How to get current css value defined by media query in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I am developing a site where I want to access a menu `display` property. If the menu is closed (`display: none`) then I want to  open it, if it's open (`display: block`) then I want to close it.

I define the menu as closed in responsive media query (if width is higher then menu is always visible with `!important` in media query), the rest I control in Javascript:

```
var attach_menu_control = function() {
  var $sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
  var $sidebar_content = document.querySelector('.sidebar .content')
  var $menu_opener = document.querySelector('.sidebar .menu-closed')

  var hide_menu = function() {
    console.log('Hide menu is run.')
    $sidebar_content.style.display = 'none'
    $menu_opener.style.display = 'block'
    $sidebar.style.width = '40px'
  }

  var show_menu = function() {
    console.log('Show menu is run.')
    $sidebar_content.style.display = 'block'
    $menu_opener.style.display = 'none'
    $sidebar.style.width = '270px'
  }

  var click_handler = function(e){
    console.log('Click handler is run.')
    debugger
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if ($sidebar_content.style.display == 'none') { // Here it is `""` instead of `none`
      show_menu()
    } else if (width <= 724) {
      hide_menu()
    }
  }

  var $main = document.querySelector('main')

  $main.addEventListener('click', hide_menu)
  $sidebar.addEventListener('click', click_handler)

  var event = new Event('click');
  $sidebar.dispatchEvent(event)
}
```

Problem is, the first time this is run - the `$sidebar_content.style.display` is an empty string `""` even though if I check it is definitely `display: none` in media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 724px) {


    /* Force sideback to be in closed mode when new page is opened */
    .sidebar {
        width: 40px;
    }

    .sidebar .content {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**Where can I get the values defined by media queries in Javascript?** I don't want to access the rules themselves, I just want to know what's the current set value..

The site is here: [www.saulesinterjerai.lt](http://www.saulesinterjerai.lt)

Comment: Is jQuery an option?

Comment: @ItayGanor no, would like to stick to Javascript, but if jQuery can do it then should Javascript too. If you can point to the relevant part of jQuery source - that would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing CSS media query rules via JavaScript/DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696124/accessing-css-media-query-rules-via-javascript-dom)

Comment: Why set styles with javascript if you can do that all in the media queries for the right sizes? I guess all you need to do in javascript is have a button to toggle a class open/close on the menu but try to avoid setting styles there. Also I don't see a reason for this to work to use `!important`

Comment: Thanks @caramba I fixed what needed with your comment. I still use !important but for forcing menu to visible when the window is wide. The general question still stands though and would be curious on how to get the right value currently applied to DOM from JS

Comment: Is the `display` property set via CSS to `.sidebar .content` no matter what size screen is/has? And still you do not need `!important` for that. if you set up a fiddle with your navigation and explain how it should look on which sizes I'm ready to help

Comment: It is not set if screen is large, as it has to be visible at all times in that case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the original question correctly, then the desire is to be able to read the current CSS values once @media settings have been taken into account.

I believe that the following should suffice as it reads out the current rendered state of the element.

`window.getComputedStyle($sidebar_content)`

Important note - In modern browsers, there can be a delay between setting a style or class, and the re-flow of the page. It may therefore be necessary to set a timeout and read the computed value after a short pause. YMMV.