# How to obtain a current CSS value defined by media queries via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

My title for this question is almost exactly the same as an existing question, but the answer below isn't applicable, unfortunately:

[How to get current css value defined by media query in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736557/how-to-get-current-css-value-defined-by-media-query-in-javascript)

First of all, I'm trying to determine what a particular CSS class value is *before* any element has been created using that particular class.

Second, I want to get the value as stated in the stylesheet, as a percentage, not recomputed as a pixel value as would be done using `getComputedStyle`.

A third complication (yes, as if I needed more!) is that the class is defined in the stylesheet for a particular Angular component, not in a global stylesheet. I can't find any of my Angular component-specific classes listed under `document.styleSheets`.

On top of that, even if I move the class to a global stylesheet instead, and look through all of the `CSSStyleRules`s of all of the `CSSStyleSheet`s listed by `document.styleSheets`, while I can find the rules for that particular class, those rules unfortunately don't reflect any of the changes dynamically made by media queries.

Here's the particular CSS involved:

```
.my-class {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

@media all and (min-width: 0) {
  .my-class {
    width: 94%;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .my-class {
    width: 47%;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .my-class {
    width: 31.5%;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1366px) {
  .my-class {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1700px) {
  .my-class {
    width: 19%;
  }
}
```

What I want, when I receive a `resize` event from the browser window, is to know what width, *as a percentage*, has been chosen by the CSS and the media queries. That way I can know how many items using my class can be displayed horizontally, and then use that value in a computation to figure out how many items for a virtually-paged list of items should be fetched from the server.

There is one solution I'm pretty sure I can use, but it's not ideal: [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

The problem with monitoring media queries via JavaScript is that the JavaScript code would have to be manually synced with any changes in the CSS, with a separate `matchMedia` for every breakpoint in the CSS.

Comment: If your whole goal is to calculate layouts why can't you just check the `window.innerWidth()` on resize and do the math? Why do you need to know what the CSS tells the browser to do instead of what it's actually doing?

Comment: Because someone else maintains the CSS, and could change their mind about how many items should be fit into different screen sizes. The individual items don't have a fixed width, so I can't just divide the screen width with by a particular width and get a result that will reliably match what the CSS is doing.

Comment: I guess I'm confused how the breakpoints in CSS are telling the browser to do something different than `element.innerWidth/window.innerWidth*100` = percentage width of .my-class at the moment you checked... That should be the same as CSS `.my-class { width: xx%; }`

Comment: `element.innerWidth` isn't a fixed size, and the elements won't always exist first so that you could even check `element.innerWidth` beforehand to do that division. It's the CSS that determines how many columns there will be, and that's based purely on the specific breakpoints in the media queries. There is no particular formula that was used to compute those breakpoint and the related percentage widths that I could replicate based on JavaScript looking only at `window.innerWidth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options came to my mind

1 (as you mentioned)

```
// reverse because you are looking for min width, If the min width is 1300 you know that all the values after it will be false (in the reversed arr)
const breakPointSizes = [0, 768, 1024, 1366, 1700].reverse()
const widths = [94, 47, 31, 23, 19].reverse() // You will have to match manually with what you have in css

const mediaMatches = breakPointSizes.map(size =>
  window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${size}px)`)
)

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  const indexOf = mediaMatches.findIndex(mediaMatch => mediaMatch.matches)
  const width = widths[indexOf]
  console.log(width)
})
```

If you want a dynamic way then what i suggest to do is have a unique element of that class hidden somewhere in the dom, and then calculate the percentage based on the current value

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const contatinerWidth = document.getElementById('container').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const elmWidth = document.getElementById('elm').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const percentage = elmWidth / contatinerWidth;
  // At this point you know whats the percentage that should be given by your css class
  console.log(percentage)
})
```

```css
#container {
 position: fixed;
 top: -300px; 
 /* So no one can see it **/
 width: 100vw;
}

.test {
 width: 50%;
}

  

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .test {
        width: 70%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="elm" class="test">
<div>
```

Comment: It's funny you just posted this, because I was giving up on finding anything better than using `mediaMatch`. I used a listener for each `MediaQueryList`, but your solution using a window resize event is cleaner (although I'll probably debounce it so it's not triggered too often). I'll post my solution as a separate answer just for comparison (since it's too big for a comment), but I think I'll modify my solution after to be closer to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something just before @ehab posted his solution. Both depend on copying the various media breakpoint widths from the CSS (which I'd still like to avoid, if possible), but ehab's solution was better than my original because it uses just one window resize listener instead of multiple `MediaQueryList` listeners.

I've modified my solution below to take his better idea into account, to use a component resize listener instead of a window resize listener ([detect-resize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-resize)) , and to add some debouncing and listener clean-up.

```
  private columnCount = 1;
  private readonly screenWidths = [768, 1024, 1366, 1700];

  onResize = debounce(() => this.getColumnCount(), 100);

  private getColumnCount(): void {
    this.columnCount = 1;

    this.screenWidths.forEach((width, index) => {
      const mql = window.matchMedia(`all and (min-width: ${width}px)`);

      if (mql.matches) {
        this.columnCount = index + 2;
      }
    });

    console.log('column count:', this.columnCount);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    addResizeListener(this.gridRef.nativeElement, this.onResize);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    removeResizeListener(this.gridRef.nativeElement, this.onResize);
  }
```